# Very simple query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

**This is View_count in my table:**

| ID | USER_P_ID | V_ID | VIEW COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | V1 | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | V1 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | V1 | 1 |
| 4 | 12 | V2 | 1 |
| 5 | 11 | V3 | 1 |
| 6 | 13 | V3 | 1 |
| 7 | 12 | V2 | 1 |

**I want result like below:**

| V_ID | VIEW COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| V1 | 2 |
| V2 | 1 |
| V3 | 2 |

Main thing in that table is both V_ID and USER_P_ID is unique. I want filter the data by V_ID. A user can view multiple V_ID is. If a user view V1 I put one insert into this table. I want to show only one view per user, Multiple views don't need to calculate.

For example: user id 10 can view the V1 10 times, but I need to calculate only one view count. How to do that in MySQL?

Comment: Count(distinct usr_p_id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT `v_id`,COUNT(DISTINCT `user_p_id`)as v_count  FROM `view_count` GROUP BY `v_id`